# How to select multiple id from table row containing multiple ids and seaching data as an array

Tags: mysql

[image: See Data stored]

How to select rows where value is in array?

```
SELECT * WHERE find_in_set ('1','2',3',classid)
```

where class id stored as multiple id like 1,24,5,6

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbac415/2

```
SELECT * WHERE find_in_set ('1',2','3',classid)
```

Which doesn't work. Is there another way to do this?
where `classid` stored as multiple ids

Comment: Seems you might want something like `SELECT * WHERE find_in_set IN ('1',2','3',classid)` ?

Comment: You can use multiple `find_in_set`s with AND/OR

Comment: @Gekkie this is not working

Comment: @vatev give an example

Comment: use IN keyword for multiple where. Also you can use  a query for getting group. like : 'Select * from where id IN (select id from y)'

Comment: @MertAkkanat this is not working

Comment: You should definitely look up database normalization. Everything else will only hurt

Comment: @NicoHaase this is not duplicate .. this question is different from others

Comment: Can you explain that? Have you tried to solve your problem using the linked answer? What makes the difference?

Comment: I have already tried. see table row containing multiple ids. And  searching query has an array . like find_in_set('1,2',tablerow)

Comment: i also advice you reading [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) .. *"Which doesn't work. Is there another way to do this? where classid stored as multiple ids
"* Yes that approach is called [Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Well there is a other approach if you can't normalize if this is a existing running production application database.. You can parse out delimited list to records but it's is [complex](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbac415/10) then you can use anny SQL operator on those records as normal..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE (classid1, classid2, classid3, classidn) 
IN ((1, 2, 3, 4), ... ,(2, 6, 9, 12));
```

Comment: This is not working classid stored as a string . please check screen shot in question